# Necessity of "the"?

Tags: articles

What is the necessity of the article "the" in the following two sentences?

> "All the other variables are defined as above"

See reference:
Carneiro, A., Portugal, P., & Varejão, J. (2014). Catastrophic job destruction during the Portuguese economic crisis. Journal of Macroeconomics, 39, 444-457.

> "All other variables are defined as above"

See reference: Thornton, J., & Esposto, F. (2003). How important are economic factors in choice of medical specialty?. Health economics, 12(1), 67-73.

Both researches are published in academic journals, therefore, both are peer reviewed (and thus the reliability of those sentences has been verified). So, in this context, what's the difference?

Comment: There is no obvious semantic difference but without a preceding context, it is hard to say.

Comment: @WeatherVane Good point. It largely depends on whether the nature of the "other variables" are understood between speaker and interlocutor - or whether they are merely hypothetical. Definite ones would command a definite article, undefined ones would not.

Comment: They mean exactly the same thing to me -- it's implicit in both cases that the authors have just defined some but not all variables. You need to be careful not to read too much into the results of peer review. A vanishing small number of peer reviews would verify the reliability of any text at this level of detail. That's not the principal reason for peer review, and for that all authors should be thankful.

Comment: @RichardKayser Whenever one uses the definite article it should be about something definite. If I say to you "Your results are better than the others" - you have every entitlement to ask "Which others?". There must be some specific people I am talking about, if not known by name then by category, or some loose identification. However "Your results are better than others" - provides far less certainty that there are identifiable "others".

Answer (score 1):

"All the other variables" implies that they are known and being referred to by using the word "the".

"All other variables" implies all variables, known, unknown, or that may someday be known. It sounds more like it's covering everything in existence.

If I had five automobiles and said, "Two are cars and all other automobiles are trucks," it would sound like every other automobile in the world is a truck.

Alternatively, if I say, "Two are cars and all **the** other automobiles are trucks," it refers more to a predefined set of cars.